# Why does Django's BooleanField's BoundField return sometimes string, sometimes boolean in template?

Tags: python, django, forms

When the form loads with initial values or when the form loads being bound (`form = SkierForm(request.POST)`) and `form.is_valid()`,

```
form['field_name'].value()
```

returns `False` (bool) in the template!

When the form does not validate on `form = SkierForm(request.POST)` then `form['field_name'].value()` returns `False` (string) in the template.

I am really unhappy about this because it makes checking the state of a BooleanField harder (in order to set the correct state for a checkbox, for example).

This is the model definition:

```
BOOLEAN_YN = (
    (True, _('Ja')),
    (False, _('Nein')),
)
field_name = models.BooleanField(_("A boolean field"), default=False, choices=BOOLEAN_YN)
```

The field value in the Django template is called like

```
{% for value, text in form.field_name.field.choices %}
   {{ value }}
   {% if form.field_name.value == value %}checked!{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why are you rendering your field like this? Why not just `{{ form.field_name }}`?

Comment: There is a lot of custom HTML / CSS magic that renders a fully customised checkbox.